# sed: match a string between two different consecutive matches on all occurrencies

Tags: sed, string-manipulation

i have:

```
bananaOPENqwertyCLOSErandomtextOPENgrapesCLOSEwhateverOPENsunshineCLOSEgreymoon
```

this line could have many more OPEN and CLOSE strings in it.

I want to print the whole line with only whatever is between any consecutive OPEN and CLOSE and discard anything else. 
ie i want the output like this:

```
qwertygrapessunshine
```

closest i can think of is:
`sed -n 's/OPEN\(.*\)CLOSE/\1/g;p'`
which obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `sed` matches are "greedy" (more precisely, leftmost-longest), this is tricky.  Try:

```
$ sed 's/OPEN/\n/g; s/[^\n]*\n//; s/CLOSE[^\n]*\n//g; s/CLOSE.*$//' file
qwertygrapessunshine
```

The above was tested on GNU `sed`.  If you are on BSD/MacOS, some minor but annoying changes will likely be required.

#### How it works

Remember that sed, by default, reads in one line at a time into its pattern space.  This means that, when we start processing a pattern space, it will never contain a newline character.  Thus, we can use a newline character, `\n`, as a marker with no possibility of ambiguity.

- `s/OPEN/\n/g`

  Replace `OPEN` with newlines

  By default, `sed` reads in only one line at a time into its pattern space.  That means that the pattern space will never, on its own, have a newline character in it.
- `s/[^\n]*\n//`

  Remove everything before the first `OPEN` (which is now a newline).

  Note that `[\n]*` matches zero or more of anything except a newline character. Consequently, `[^\n]*\n` matches zero or more of anything except a newline followed by a newline. This means it matches up to and including the *next* newline. By contrast, because sed expressions are "greedy" (leftmost-longest), `.*\n` matches anything up to and including the *last* newline in the pattern space.
- `s/CLOSE[^\n]*\n//g`

  Remove everything starting from `CLOSE` and going to the next newline.
- `s/CLOSE.*$//`

  Remove from the last `CLOSE` to the end of the line.

Comment: beautifully explained. could you also tell me what is [^\n]* and what's the difference between it and things like .*

Comment: Thank you.  `[\n]*` matches zero or more of anything __except__ a newline character.  `[^\n]*\n` matches zero or more of anything except a newline followed by a newline.  This means it matches up to and including the next newline.  By contrast, `.*\n` matches up to and including the __last__ newline in the pattern space.

Comment: Understood. Thank you